# How to Refresh GridView?

Tags: android

How to Refresh Grid view?

I was download image from RSS Site using Image Loader Class but the main Problem is the images was displayed in grid view after i was scrolling the grid view many times otherwise default image is displayed.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

the GridView has an invalidateViews() method.

when you call this method: "all the views to be rebuilt and redrawn." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Answer (score 0):

the above one will work

Or

you can put the data collection into a method and make calls to this method every time the page reloads or for any user interaction like pulling the scroll bar but better use for page refresh

let me know if it helped

hope it works

have a great day

Comment: how to do page refresh rajesh?

Comment: `the above one will work` what are you trying to refer here.

Comment: In my application the image is displayed after i will scroll grid many times otherwise not display.

Comment: @rajesh, answers can change order on the page depending on how many up or down votes they receive. So "the above one" is ambiguous. Please clarify which of the other answers you meant.